# Embedded database with row locking feature for c#

Tags: c#, database

Please do suggest an embedded database with row locking feature for c# ?

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded"? Would SQL Server Express serve? SQL Server CE?

Comment: Yep.. I meant dbs that can be shipped with application. Not only the MS products but thirdparty also.

Answer (score 2):

Firebird might be an option if you are looking for a free one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "row locking features" in this context, but have you looked at [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that a self-defeating request? If you are embedding the database then it's just accessing a file from your executable. The file wouldn't support row locking and any row locking by the embedded database would be limited to the scope of your application. Are you building a multi-threaded application?

Comment: In that case I withdraw my statement ;) I know of Nexus which I know is used in a heavily multithreaded application, it's also seriously fast. I don't know specifically if it's used with row locking.

Comment: Hi Lazarus, thanks for your help. I was googling to know more about Nexus.

Answer (score 1):

ESENT is an embedded database which is part of Windows (the Active Directory uses it). It has row locking but no query engine. The managed interface is here:

http://managedesent.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand why you would need row locking with an embedded database? Are you using multiple threads for access across multiple connections or transactions? or are you assuming that other processes can access the datafile?

Assuming that the row locking is a mistake, Microsoft offers a good choice with SQL Server Compact edition (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx). This is fully embeddable, and is reasonably compatible with the full SQL Server stack.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the excelent (dual license) [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst) database.
**Disclaimer:** I don't have any relation with the company, just tried the product in the past.